How to deal with localized conditionnel expression within strings
I have this Text in SwiftUI :
Text("Level \(level.id)" + (level.isEnded ? " ended" : ""))

This string does not automatically go to the Strings catalog.
What is the best way to deal with this kind of text and localization ?
Thanks

You could put the text together using individual words or parts of a sentence, but this can get complicated for full sentences in different languages.
When the number of cases is limited as with your example, I would suggest using separate translations instead:
Text(level.isEnded ? "LEVEL_ENDED \(level.id)" : "LEVEL_NOT_ENDED \(level.id)")

"LEVEL_ENDED %lld" = "Level %lld ended";
"LEVEL_NOT_ENDED %lld" = "Level %lld";

